# SQL CLR not properly enabling

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, 64-bit, sqlclr

We have a SQL server running SQL 2005 Workgroup 64 bit (9.0.4273), on Windows 2003 server 64 bit.

We have run sp_configure and reconfigured the server which indicates that the clr is now enabled.

```
exec sp_configure 'clr enabled', '1'
go
reconfigure
go
```

However, when trying to call CREATE ASSEMBLY the server completely dies on us and we have to do a full reboot of the machine.

A little more diagnostic information, even though clr enabled is set to 1 and we have rebooted the full server, running the following statement

```
select * from sys.dm_clr_properties
```

returns

```
directory   
version 
state   locked CLR version with mscoree
```

which is what it says when the CLR is not enabled on another machine.

On a correctly enabled machine (after reboot) this function reads

```
directory   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\
version v2.0.50727
state   CLR is initialized
```

Comment: Any errors? or just dies silently?

Comment: dies silently, no event log entries or anything in sql event log

Answer (score 0):

The query may not be display the CLR version properly if you don't have `VIEW SERVER STATE` permissions on the server.

Check your login that is running the query has `VIEW SERVER STATE` permissions. One method is grant that login 'db_owner' to the database and re-run the query, you should get the correct results then.

More info about `sys.dm_clr_properties`: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms174983.aspx]

Comment: Thanks for the reply nik, it's nearly 6yrs since we had this issue though and we no longer have the server in question so I cannot prove if your suggestion would help.